# how to make display the data in object to the CSV file using java code

Tags: java, csv

Let me know is it possible to move the data in an object to the csv file using java code and if possible Please give a small description on how does it possible.Thankyou in advance...

Comment: Are you attempting to generate a CSV from an object? What have you tried?

Comment: Actually i tried by using csvlistwriter,when i'm trying to redirect my data to the csv file, them i'm getting whole my data in a single column and cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in Java using supercsv library. Check this link, you can directly construct beans out of the csv file.

http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html

Though you can also achieve the same without using any library.